# How to execute an exe file supply the input text file and get the output in a variable in Python 3 on Windows?

Tags: python-3.x

I have an exe file mycode.exe at `"D:\projFolder\mycode.exe"` and an input text file in.txt at `"D:\projFolder\in.txt"`.

I am writing a Python3 script which will execute this `exe` file with the supplied input text and compare the output.

To achieve it, I am just trying to execute Windows command as :

```
cmd> "D:\projFolder\mycode.exe" < "D:\projFolder\in.txt"
```

and want to save the result of the above command in a variable say, `resultstdout`, and later use it to compare with an expected output file `out.txt.`

**My problem, how to execute the Windows command `"D:\projFolder\mycode.exe" < "D:\projFolder\in.txt"` in `Python3` script?**

I was previously working on Python2 and I was achieving it as follows:

```
baseDirectory = "D:/projFolder"

( stat, consoleoutput ) = subprocess.getstatusoutput(baseDirectory + "/mycode.exe"+ " < " + contestDirectory+ "/" +in.txt)

if(stat == 0):
    # Perform result comparision
else:
    # Some execption while executing the command.
```

However, I am not sure on how to refactor the above code in Python 3.

Comment: What problems did you run into?

Comment: What was your approach when finding a solution for Python 2.x and where are you stuck applying that to python 3.x?